# How to Do Facebook Login Using 'wp_insert_user'?

Tags: json, wordpress, facebook-javascript-sdk, wordpress-theming

I am building a user generated content sharing theme and I want to make a custom Facebook connect. After researching, I found out this code.

The following code is adding the app to the users profile in Facebook, but is not creating a new user and also doesn't makes them logged in.

Here is the full code (to be added in `functions.php`).

### Step 1 - Intializing javascript at header area

```
function fb_head(){
    if( is_user_logged_in() ) 
        return;
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.fbAsyncInit = function(){
            FB.init({
                appId:'APP_ID', 
                status:true, 
                cookie:true, 
                xfbml:true, 
                oauth:true
            });
        };
    </script>
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        (function() {
            var e = document.createElement('script');
            e.type = 'text/javascript';
            e.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
            e.async = true;
            document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
        }());
    </script>
    <?php
}
add_action( 'wp_head', 'fb_head' );
```

### Step 2 - Inserting a button for facebook login

```
<button id="facebook_connect">Connect with facebook</button>
```

### Step 3 - Loading Jquery Library

```
function mytheme_enqueue_scripts(){
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'mytheme_enqueue_scripts');
```

### Step 4 - Add a jQuery on-click function to the button we have created

This code will be placed on the wp footer section (before the closing body tag).

```
function fb_footer(){
    if( is_user_logged_in()):
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'> jQuery('#facebook_connect').hide(); </script>";
        return;
    endif;
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery('#facebook_connect').click(function(){
            FB.login(function(FB_response){
                if( FB_response.status === 'connected' ){
                    fb_intialize(FB_response);
                }
            },
            {scope: 'email'});
        });

        function fb_intialize(FB_response){
            FB.api( 
                '/me', 
                'GET', 
                {'fields':'id,email,username,verified,name'},
                function(FB_userdata){
                    jQuery.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                        url: 'AJAXURL',
                        data: {
                            "action": "fb_intialize", 
                            "FB_userdata": FB_userdata, 
                            "FB_response": FB_response
                        },
                        success: function(user){
                            if( user.error ){
                                alert( user.error );
                            }
                            else if( user.loggedin ){
                                window.location.reload();
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            );
        };
    </script>
    <?php
}
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'fb_footer' );
```

### Step 5 - MAIN STEP: Adding the handler function

```
function wp_ajax_fb_intialize(){
    @error_reporting( 0 ); // Don't break the JSON result
    header( 'Content-type: application/json' );

    if( !isset( $_REQUEST['FB_response'] ) || !isset( $_REQUEST['FB_userdata'] ))
        die( json_encode( array( 'error' => 'Authonication required.' )));

    $FB_response = $_REQUEST['FB_response'];
    $FB_userdata = $_REQUEST['FB_userdata'];
    $FB_userid = (int) $FB_userdata['id'];

    if( !$FB_userid )
        die( json_encode( array( 'error' => 'Please connect your facebook account.' )));

    global $wpdb;
    $user_ID = $wpdb->get_var( "SELECT user_id FROM $wpdb->usermeta WHERE meta_key = '_fbid' AND meta_value =  '$FB_userid'" );

    if( !$user_ID ){
        $user_email = $FB_userdata['email'];
        $user_ID = $wpdb->get_var( "SELECT ID FROM $wpdb->users WHERE user_email = '$user_email'" );

        if( !$user_ID ){
            if ( !get_option( 'users_can_register' ))
                die( json_encode( array( 'error' => 'Registration is not open at this time. Please come back later..' )));

            extract( $FB_userdata );

            $display_name = $name;
            $user_login = $username;

            if( empty( $verified ) || !$verified )
                die( json_encode( array( 'error' => 'Your facebook account is not verified. You hae to verify your account   before proceed login or registering on this site.' )));

            $user_email = $email;
            if ( empty( $user_email ))
                die( json_encode( array( 'error' => 'Please re-connect your facebook account as we couldnt find your email  address..' )));

            if( empty( $name ))
                die( json_encode( array( 'error' => 'empty_name', 'We didnt find your name. Please complete your facebook   account before proceeding..' )));

            if( empty( $user_login ))
                $user_login = sanitize_title_with_dashes( sanitize_user( $display_name, true ));

            if ( username_exists( $user_login ))
                $user_login = $user_login. time();

            $user_pass = wp_generate_password( 12, false );
            $userdata = compact( 'user_login', 'user_email', 'user_pass', 'display_name' );

            $user_ID = wp_insert_user( $userdata );
            if ( is_wp_error( $user_ID ))
                die( json_encode( array( 'error' => $user_ID->get_error_message())));

            update_user_meta( $user_ID, '_fbid', (int) $id );
        }
        else{
            update_user_meta( $user_ID, '_fbid', (int) $FB_userdata['id'] );
        }
    }

    wp_set_auth_cookie( $user_ID, false, false );
    die( json_encode( array( 'loggedin' => true )));
}
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_fb_intialize', 'wp_ajax_fb_intialize' );
```

THis is how I add the Facebook button:

```
 <button id="facebook_connect">Connect with Facebook</button>
```

If anyone is trying it please replace the App ID.

Comment: And the error is on the last step as I said that it is adding the app to users profile but isn't creating a new user in my WP site

Comment: I had added the information in 1st Para

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Changed the ajax url from

```
url: 'AJAXURL',
```

to

```
url: '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>',
```

One thing I noticed while testing was that if I delete a user from the wp_users table the user meta with the facebook id will still be there so you may need to check if the facebook id is associated with an invalid user id in your ajax callback e.g.

```
global $wpdb;
$user_ID = $wpdb->get_var( "SELECT user_id FROM $wpdb->usermeta WHERE meta_key = '_fbid' AND meta_value =  '$FB_userid'" );

// check if the user id is valid
if( false === ($check_user = get_userdata($user_ID)) )
{
  $user_ID = false; // set to false to force create a new user
}
```

The rest of your code worked fine.

Comment: Thanks for ur answer I am in my mobile right now I will check it tonight

Comment: hello
it is creating all users with my name vaibhav bhanushali

Comment: It will select the username from the connected FB account. Have you tried connecting with a different Facebook ID?

Comment: Yes
and even with different computer and different browsers

Comment: I will explain you U will first connect with Facebook id a  so it will fetch U R Facebook data and email say hi a and next U will connect with b .it  will show hi a and also email of a even U have connected with b

Comment: I can't replicate this problem. Have you logged out of FB before trying to connect?

Comment: YEs, I've created new WP accounts with multiple FB user logins.

Answer (score 5):

Thanks for the code! Worked like a charm. But there is one really important security thing I discovered!

In the console I just changed facebook variables before sending the ajax request and I could login with everyones fb account (if you know their facebook id). The next couple of lines also check the fb token and validates if the login really is valid!

So in your **wp_ajax_fb_intialize** function you should definetely add these couple of lines:

```
$FB_response = $_REQUEST['FB_response'];
$FB_userdata = $_REQUEST['FB_userdata'];
$FB_userid = (int) $FB_userdata['id'];

//NEW CODE INSERT - check if token is valid
$token = $FB_response['authResponse']['accessToken'];
$path = 'https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token='.$token;
$content = @file_get_contents($path);
$fb_user = json_decode($content);
if ($fb_user->id != $FB_userdata['id'])
    die( json_encode( array( 'error' => 'FB login error' )));
```

I used file_get_contents but it is also possible to use curl

Comment: file_get_contents isnt allowed in wordpress